# Cmake Error Compiler not set

Tags: c++, gcc, build, cmake

I'm using `cmake` version 3.10.2 and I'm having trouble build despite having everything to do so.

When I'm trying to use cmake on a directory as shown below I get the message that I dont have the c compiler set nor the c++ compiler.

```
XXXXXX@XXXXX:~/XXXXX$ cmake .
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  /usr/local/bin/gcc.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/XXXXXX/XXXXX/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Which is weird because I have specifically set those in my .bashrc like so:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
```

I've had this error in the past once before I AFAIK I fixed it by repeatedly trying to build and deleting the cmake cache files.

Reinstalling `build-essential` or in my case the arch analogue `base-devel` did not help, and I'm out of ideas what could be causing this.

Comment: And *are* there the `/usr/local/bin/gcc` and `/usr/local/bin/g++` programs? Do they exist? Why do you have the (Linux) standard compilers in a non-standard location? What if you *unset* the environment variables?

Comment: that fixed it, I thought I had put the output of `which gcc` into the export. feel kind of stupid now. you've saved me quite a headache, put it up as an answer and I'll accept